# iOS Custom Framework .framework file

Tags: ios, frameworks

I've followed this tutorial:

https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework

and have everything working on the development end. Even the dependent product works fine.  In the end I have a .framework, .a, headers folder, and include folder after building.  The article says you just have to drag the .framework over to your project and include #include  However, when I do this and build I get a linker error:

```
ld: framework not found MyFramework
```

Please remember, I have this working, linking, etc in my dependent project but in that project I copied the Framework project into the Testing project.  Are there missing steps I have to do after dragging the .framwork over? I've tried dragging the .a as well with no success (same error message).

Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above tutorial you need to make sure you remove the Copy Files Build phase that the latest version of XCode adds. This was caused because of this step. Everything else was correctly added.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you have the framework structure completely correct?  Since you were just using it as a subproject before you may well not be building the framework directory correctly.

It should look like:

```
MyFramework.framework     //(directory)
  info.plist
  MyFramework             //(symbolic link to Versions/Current/MyFramework)
  Resources               //(symbolic link to Versions/Current/Resources)
  Headers                 //(symbolic link to Versions/Current/Headers)
  Versions                //(directory)
    Current               //(symbolic link to directory "A" below)
    A                     //(directory)
      Headers             //(directory containing framework headers)
      Resources           //(directory holding framework resources)
      MyFramework         //(actual compiled library, really a .a file)
```

The .a file in your framework should not end in .a.  And as noted all of those symbolic links have to be right, an "`ls -l`" in your framework directory should look like:

```
drwxr-xr-x   7 kendall  admin   238B Feb 19 13:36 ./
drwxr-xr-x  11 kendall  admin   374B Feb 19 13:36 ../
lrwxr-xr-x   1 kendall  admin    24B Feb 19 13:36 Headers@ -> Versions/Current/Headers
lrwxr-xr-x   1 kendall  admin    30B Feb 19 13:36 MyFramework@ -> Versions/Current/MyFramework
lrwxr-xr-x   1 kendall  admin    26B Feb 19 13:36 Resources@ -> Versions/Current/Resources
drwxr-xr-x   4 kendall  admin   136B Feb 19 13:36 Versions/
-rw-r--r--   1 kendall  admin   215B Feb 19 13:36 info.plist
```

The contents of info.plist (which tells the linker what the name of the static library in the framework really is) look like:

```
CFBundleDevelopmentRegion
English
CFBundleExecutable
MyFramework
CFBundleIdentifier
com.pushio.pushiomanager
CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion
6.0
CFBundlePackageType
FMWK
CFBundleSignature
????
CFBundleVersion
1.0.0
```

Comment: Ow, that actually is much more likely the right answer. LD knows about the framework, hence the OP has correctly added it in the linking phase. It sounds like a broken framework - e.g. missing static library. +1

Comment: I don't have any resources so I have: MyFramework and Headers (symbolic links) and Versions folder. In Versions I have A-Headers (no MyFramework). I also don't have an Info.plist.

Comment: Just on a quick note, I am following the link mentioned above not the one mentioning how to create a versioned one.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need an info.plist because it's what indicates the name of the executable... I added information about what goes in there.

Answer (score 2):

*) I suppose you missed clicking the checkbox "Copy items into destination groups folder(if needed)" when you dragged or copied the framework over.

*) And also make sure you link the framework by going to project -> targets -> Build phases ->Link binary with Libraries and adding the framework.